# JSPs and Active Directory

Tags: jsp, active-directory

I'm working on a "change password" JSP which must connect with Active Directory, and let a user change his/her password.

It seems like JNDI is the way to go, is this correct? Has anyone here done this before?

The examples I'll be following are http://gwallen.com/code/java/activedirectory.php#deleteDupes and http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/examples/directory.html

Am I on the right track? Any tips, warnings, or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring LDAP's [LdapTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) provides quick and easy way to access/modify LDAP entries.
[This thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?33493-how-to-change-password-of-Activity-Directory-by-Spring-LDAP) on Spring Forum should help you. Just remember, use ldaps:// and create manager DN with sufficient privileges.